# PYTHON | Copying a file from an unknown destination

Tags: python, directory, copy

Hi my name is Oscar and I would like some help!
So the scenario I have is that I am trying to write a python code that will copy itself and put that copy in another directory. I know that you can use the shutil command. For example:

import shutil
shutil.copy("C:\Users\%user%\Downloads\file.txt", "C:\Users\%user%\Documents")

But I want to just copy the file so that the script works on any computer that it is located on, for example:

import shutil
shutil.copy("file.txt", "C:\Users\%user%\Documents")

If you don't understand what I mean please ask and I can try to elaborate.

Sincerely, Oscar :)

EDIT: I am super dumb it seems like, I did not know that you had to type the destination folder with to backslashes sometimes to actually make it a path. All solved, sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use pythons standard "os" library to make OS independent filepaths. Then you use the special "**file**" variable available inside any executed script to get the location of the executed script, to copy itself to some target location. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The filename of a python file is available using:

```
import sys

print(sys.argv[0])
```

You can use this filename to copy the same file elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I am super dumb it seems like, I did not know that you had to type the destination folder with to backslashes sometimes to actually make it a path. All solved, sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Comment: these things happen in the beginning. Try to break down the problem and for any question you have, e.g. "how to specify a file path?", search on Google or whatever your favourite search engine is. Good luck!