# How I used tkinter button to Import files

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I would like to run a python program and when clicking a button in a (tkinter) window become import files form any direction and store it to another direction and in database .

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
def UploadAction(event=None):
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilenames()
    print('Selected:', filename)
root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(root, text='import files', command=UploadAction) 
button.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What's your code?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA 

this is just open button and select file , but i need to select files and store it in another direction and database .



import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

def UploadAction(event=None):
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilenames()
    print('Selected:', filename)

root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(root, text='import files', command=UploadAction)
button.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)

root.mainloop()

Comment: Add your code to your post,instead of comment.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA I add my code to post .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PYTHON | Copying a file from an unknown destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53109247/python-copying-a-file-from-an-unknown-destination)

Comment: @stovfl thanks deer, but this not same as my code

Comment: ***not same as my code***: Your code shows nothing about file handling? So how would anything the same as yours? Follow the linked examples and you would get what you want or rephrase your question and explain what else you want.